# Windows not detecting Bluetooth device; but device detecting Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, android, bluetooth

I am trying to pair my Windows 8.1 machine to my Moto G. Both devices have Bluetooth switched on and the Moto G is able to see my Windows machine in the Bluetooth settings, but upon trying to connect I get the error "Can't communicate with [name]".

I can't find the Moto G on Windows when I go to "Add a device". I've tried adding different Bluetooth devices but none of them appear.

What is stopping Windows from finding devices, but not the other way around?

Comment: [To make your computer discoverable to Bluetooth enabled devices, select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-bluetooth-device-settings#1TC=windows-7)